# Prevent API call based on a timer in vue.js

Tags: vue.js

In a scenario, the GET API call takes around 1 minute to fetch the updated data, updated by INSERT/UPDATE API calls.

So user updates some fields in the UI, and a UPDATE call has been made, the UPDATE call returns the updated fields value. However if the user refreshes the page with 1 minute of updating, the GET call will be made and which returns the OLD data.

How can I prevent the GET CALL within 1 minute of updating data?

Answer (score 1):

1. Get  data
2. Save data in `localStorage`, and note `timeStamp` i `localStorage`
3. Get data from `localStorage` if current time is less than 1 minute after `timeStamp`
4. Else get new data